# GraphQL: How to pass Query Variables via playground?

Tags: graphql

I am following [Andrew Mead's tutorial on Gatsby](https://youtu.be/8t0vNu2fCCM?t=10614) and for some reason I am having trouble with passing query variables to the query via GraphQL playground. As far as I can tell, the query works on node, as the contents of the 'blog' are being populated.

Here is my code for the Query Variables (bottom left in GQL playground).

```
{
  "slug": "example"
}
```

And the query I am making:

```
query ($slug: String!) {
  markdownRemark (
    fields: {
      slug: {
        eq: $slug
      }
    }
  ) {
    frontmatter {
      title
      date
    }
    html
  }
}
```

However, this results in error: `"message": "Variable \"$slug\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.",`

After playing around with making the variable required and not required, I am pretty sure it is because the query variable is not being passed, but I cannot figure out why as every other resource seems to do what Andrew Mead is doing. eg. [Here](https://graphqlmastery.com/blog/graphql-quick-tip-how-to-pass-variables-in-graphiql)

The strange thing is, the query seems to work when I run it on VS Code, but not on the playground. Is there a setting I am missing?

EDIT 2019-12-18: It was a dumb mistake of mine. I had clicked on `HTTP HEADERS` on the bottom left, NOT `QUERY VARIABLES`, as Daniel Reardon kindly pointed out.

Comment: Are you sure you're entering the variables into the variables input and not the headers input? The UI is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @DanielRearden Ahh omg you're right. It was HTTP Headers that was highlighted. Stupid mistake of mine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are entering the variables into the variable field and not the headers field. You can toggle between the two by clicking upon the appropriate tab above the field.

Comment: holy crap, thanks! I wasted at least a couple of hours trying to find the formatting error in my query before finding your answer.